# Where are Pierre Samuel's videos of Bourbaki proceedings available?

Tags: mathematics, abstract-algebra, bourbaki

Wikipedia's [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pierre_Samuel) on Pierre Samuel claims (uncitedly):

> He was a member of the Bourbaki group, and filmed some of their meetings. A French television documentary on Bourbaki broadcast some of this footage in 2000.

Does anyone know the name of this documentary? Better yet, is any of Samuel's footage available online?

Comment: Interesting. I've seen some minutes of their early meetings (1930s) typewritten, they are available on the web. But I did not know about the movies. +1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It appears to be from the following broadcast ([source](https://poincare.univ-lorraine.fr/sites/poincare.univ-lorraine.fr/files/users/documents/fichier_page/b-biblio-b-iii2013.pdf)):

> ARTE (FRANCE TÉLÉVISION - LA CINQUIÈME) Émission « Archimède » du 14 novembre 2000 consacrée à Bourbaki, réalisée avec la collaboration de Maurice Boulanger et Pierre Samuel. On a présenté de courts extraits de films d’amateur tournés par Pierre Samuel, ancien membre de Bourbaki, durant divers congrès Bourbaki. Mise en
>   ligne d’un résumé de cette émission
>   http://archives.arte-tv.com/hebdo/archimed/20001114/ftext/sujet5.html

Which (roughly) translates as:

> ARTE (FRANCE TÉLÉVISION - LA CINQUIÈME) "Archimedes" broadcast of November 14, 2000 dedicated to Bourbaki, produced with the collaboration of Maurice Boulanger and Pierre Samuel.  Short films of amateur films made by Pierre Samuel, a former member of Bourbaki, were presented during various Bourbaki congresses. Online summary of this show
>    http://archives.arte-tv.com/hebdo/archimed/20001114/ftext/sujet5.html

The online summary is no longer available, but has been [archived by the WayBack Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20050115230349/http://archives.arte-tv.com/hebdo/archimed/20001114/ftext/sujet5.html). Sadly it seems to date from 5 years after the broadcast and doesn't seem to mention the films at all.

I couldn't find the broadcast online either, though it may be possible to contact Arte directly to enquire.

Answer (score 3):

These videos (some of them, maybe) were on view during an exhibition about Bourbaki and his early collaborators at Bibliothèque de l'École normale supérieure. 
Presumably the Association des collaborateurs de N. Bourbaki still has a copy of some of these videos, I don't know if, nor how, it can share them though.